# Pages designed by Elemntor pagebuilder does not changes on the front end

Tags: wordpress, elementor

I am editing pages designed by elemntor page builder through **phpmyadmin** but no effect on front. If I disable elemntor plugin and view the pages then I see change made through **phpmyadmin**. I am editing pages in wp_posts.

I tried these methods with no luck:

1. Regenerate the CSS via Elementor > Tools > Regenerate CSS on WordPress Dashboard, then make sure that all cache cleared (server cache, caching plugins, and browser cache).
2. Switch the CSS print method in “Elementor > Settings > Advanced”

What I am missing here?

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you change the pages through Elementor itself? Changing them in the database can have unwanted side effects.

Comment: Would you change 3.8k pages with Elementor?

Comment: Valid point. Just be careful. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Probably cache ( plugin or server ).
Also you can wrongly edit post-revision instead of post in db

Comment: I am trying to replace/edit a short code from the pages. I have also tried with search and replace plugin, changes takes place in database but no changes on front end.